# In meteorjs, event variable cannot be explored due to a cyclic error

Tags: meteor

In meteorjs, alert(JSON.stringify(e,null,4)); 
(e or event being used as the event context variable)
only generated cyclic error, so I cannot explore the event variable.
If normal, how can I investigate the event variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's the weirdest way to debug something I've ever seen, respect!

Instead, just try a `console.log(e)`. You can then right click the object in the console & save it as a temp variable. Another popular one is `window.e = e` then access `e` from the console. If you'll be modifying object later on, you'll want to put a `debugger` or `return` after you send the variable to the console, otherwise the object will be modified before you look at it.